# Mongo DB: Time based filtering

Tags: mongodb, datetime, time, mongo-shell

I have loaded data into mongoDB in below format:

```
{ 
    "horizontalAccuracy" : 3.0, 
    "timestamp" : 1551390869, 
    "datetime" : ISODate("2019-02-28T18:30:00.000+0000"), 
    "month" : 3, 
    "year" : 2019, 
    "country" : "MYS" 
}
```

Now I want to run a query on this records, select records which are created between 02:00PM to 04:00PM. I would be glad to have any suggestions.

Comment: Between 2PM and 4PM of any day? Should have stored time separately for that.

Comment: Your `datetime` does not agree with `timestamp`. Are those two different moments in time?

Comment: You should be able to use [$hour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/#exp._S_hour) operator, but this will result in a fullscan of some sort, I think (collection scan or index scan)